# Exporting "user profile" to another machine in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, user-interface

How can I export the "user profile" in QGIS 3.20 to use it on another machine?

Answer (score 6):

Open the folder that stores your user profile. You can find it clicking `Menu Settings / User Profiles / Open Active Profile Folder` (see screenshot) - or see [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#user-profiles) for the default location on different operating systems.

Go to the parent directory (`profiles`) to see all profiles. Copy the folder with the profile you want to use. Than paste it in the corresponding profile folder on the other computer. You should now be able the choose this copied profile form `Menu Settings / User Profiles`.

See also: [QGIS Profiles](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/qgis-profiles).

[image]